# JS/jQuery Recalculate object constructor values from button onclick->prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, constructor, onclick

I am having trouble dynamically updating values in a jQuery-generated table.

I inserted a button next to values that the contents of adjacent `<td>` are calculated from, with the intent that the `.click(function(){ prompt("...","...")}` would not only update the value of interest (hours, avgCustomers, avgPurchase), but also recalculate the dependent `<td>`.

The contents of the table are calculated on `$(document).ready` from an object constructor, using arrays for the input values (see Shops.js @ http://github.com/jacobshillman/Week2A2.git, and/or below). In the git, 'index.html' is the page of interest.

A click event updates the value displayed, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the rest of the table to recalculate based on the new value.

```
  //Donut Shop Constructor
  function Shop (loc, hours, minCust, maxCust, avgDonCust, avgCust, donHr, donDay) {
    this.loc = loc;
    this.hours = hours;
    console.log(this.loc + ", Hours: " + this.hours);
    this.minCust = minCust;
    this.maxCust = maxCust;
    this.avgDonCust = avgDonCust;

    //Random sample of average customers per hour:
    this.avgCust = getCustpHr(this.hours, this.minCust, this.maxCust);
    console.log(this.loc + ", Customers per hour: " + this.avgCust);

    //Donuts to bake per hour:
    this.donHr = getDon(this.avgCust, this.avgDonCust)
    console.log(this.loc + ", Donuts to bake per hour: " + this.donHr);

    //Donuts to bake per day:
    this.donDay = getSum (this.donHr)
    console.log(this.loc + ", Donuts to bake per day: " + this.donDay);

    };

//Donut Shops declaration:
  var Shops = [5];

  Shops[0] = new Shop("Downtown", 8, 8, 43, 4.5);

  Shops[1] = new Shop("Capitol Hill", 24, 4, 37, 2);

  Shops[2] = new Shop("South Lake Union", 10, 9, 23, 6.33);

  Shops[3] = new Shop("Wedgewood", 7, 2, 28, 1.25);

  Shops[4] = new Shop("Ballard", 10, 8, 58, 3.75);

//Populate index.html with Donut shops stats:
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(Shops, function(){
      $row = $('<tr></tr>');
      $('#shopGrid tbody').append($row);
      $row.append($('<td><ul>' + this.loc + '<li>Hours Open: ' + 
                                            '<span id="Hour">' + this.hours + '</span>'
                                              + '<input type="button" class="edit" value="EDIT">' + '</li>'
                                          + '<li>Average Purchase:' + 
                                            '<span id="Purch">' + this.avgDonCust + '</span>'
                                              + '<input type="button" class="edit" value="EDIT">' + '</li>'
                                          + '<li>Store Traffic:' + 
                                            '<span id="Traffic">' + this.minCust + '-' + this.maxCust + '</span>'
                                              + '<input type="button" class="edit" value="EDIT">' + '</li></ul>'))
//.slice() is inserted to control formatting:
      $row.append($('<td>' + this.avgCust.slice(0,8) + '<br>'  
                           + this.avgCust.slice(8,16) + '<br>' 
                           + this.avgCust.slice(16) +'</td>'));
      $row.append($('<td>' + this.donHr.slice(0,8) + '<br>'
                           + this.donHr.slice(8,16) + '<br>'
                           + this.donHr.slice(16) + '</td>'));
      $row.append($('<td>' + this.donDay + '</td>'));

  });

//Shop stats EDIT buttons:
//If else for EDIT button fX:
  $(".edit").click(function(){
    var test = $('#Hour').text();
    console.log(test);

    var newHours = prompt("Enter new number between 0 and 24", "New Hours");
    if (newHours <= 24) {
        $('#Hour').text(newHours);
        test = newHours
      }else{
        alert('Must be a number between 0 to 24.')
      }
    console.log(test);
    console.log(document.getElementById('Hour'));
});


/*
  $(".edit").click(function(){
    if ($('#Hour')) {
      var newHours = prompt("Enter new number between 0 and 24", "New Hours");
      if (newHours <= 24) {
        $('#Hour').value(newHours);
      }else{
        alert('Must be a number between 0 to 24.')
      }
    }else if ($('#Purch')) {
      var newVal = prompt("Enter new value:", "Enter number");
        $(this.avgDonCust).val(newVal);
    }else if ($('#Traffic')) {
      var newVal = prompt("Enter first value:", "Enter number");
      $(this.minCust).value(newVal)
      var val2 = prompt("Enter second value", "Enter number");
      $(this.maxCust).value(Val2);
      };
    });
*/

/*
  //Switch for EDIT buttons fX:
  $(".edit").click(function (){
    switch (n){
      case $('#Hour')
        var newHours = prompt("Enter new number between 0 and 24", "New Hours");
        if newHours <= 24 {
          $(this.hours).val(newHours);
        }else{
          alert('Must be a number between 0 to 24.');
        break;
      case $('Purch'):
        var newVal = prompt("Enter new value:", "Enter number");
        $(this.avgDonCust).val(newVal);
      case $('#Traffic'):
        var newVal = prompt("Enter first value:", "Enter number");
        $(this.minCust).val(newVal);
        function() {
          var val2 = prompt("Enter second value", "Enter number");
          $(this.maxCust).val(Val2);
        };
        break;
    }
*/
});
```

The code commented out and in `console.log()` are my attempts at troubleshooting and getting the table to recalculate.

Best I can figure is that I need to update the corresponding value in the 2-D array Shops - `Shops[this][[1]` to update the "Hours Open:" of any given shop, then triggering the calculations again, without reloading the page.

I tried in an earlier (failed) attempt to use objects instead of arrays, but descended into defining jQuery var=s hell because I had to hand-jam all the object names into html and jQuery. This attempt can be seen in the 'Legacy' directory in the .git, above.

I've seen `updateTo()` and `recompute()`  advice on Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure whether/how I'd be able to integrate them.

Any input is greatly appreciated!  I'm not opposed to scrapping things and starting from scratch: this is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to make a working example as I'm pressed for time, but I can give you a few suggestions. These suggestions are only for if you're not coding a reusable library.

I'd create properties (functions) that recompute other properties and/or the html.

```
var _total = 0, _tax = 0, _grand = 0;

function totalChange() {
    $('#prop1').val(_prop1);
    tax(_total * .08)
    _.debounce(_grand);
}

function total(val) {
    if(val) {
        _total = val;
        totalChange();
    }
    return _total;
}
```

Then you can create a getter and setter for each of your properties that sets html or other properties.

I would actually recommend [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) or [angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) as they provide the exact functionality you're looking for.

I was bored today and created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97zvqzzh/) for you using ember. Let me know if you have an questions.

Comment: Thanks FelesMortis!!  I'm in the first couple weeks of learning JS + jQuery, so I'm not sure if I'd get much traction branching out to other flavors of JS. Conceptually, I totally get what you're saying! I don't know how to implement, though. The project's just for me to practice, so not a big deal. Have a good weekend!